# Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, select

As sometimes happens, a block of code fails and no matter how hard you try, you can't figure out where it is. In these cases a second pair of eyes sometimes sees what the brain doesn't register. I think this is one of those cases. It's almost certainly my fault and I did something wrong but I honestly can't figure out where.

This is a SELECT I wrote

```
SELECT
  `a.dev_act_id`,
  `a.dev_act_code`,
  `a.dev_act_desc`,
  `a.dev_act_type`,
  `a.lang_code`,
  `pa.dev_plan_act_id`,
  `pa.action_status`,
  `pa.action_expiration`,
  `cb.competence_id`,
  `cb.credits` AS `avail_credits`,
  `w.credits` AS `settled_credits`
FROM
  `pbq_idp_plan_actions` AS pa
  INNER JOIN `pbq_idp_dev_actions` AS a ON `pa.dev_act_id` = `a.dev_act_id`
  INNER JOIN `pbq_idp_credit_bags` AS cb ON `pa.dev_plan_act_id` = `cb.dev_plan_act_id`
  INNER JOIN `pbq_idp_wallets` AS w ON `a.dev_act_id` = `w.dev_act_id`
WHERE
  `pa.dev_plan_id` = 0
ORDER BY
  `cb.competence_id`
```

The structure of the `pbq_idp_dev_actions` table whose alias is 'a', is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `pbq_idp_dev_actions` (
  `dev_act_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `wallet_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dev_act_code` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `dev_act_desc` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `dev_act_type` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lang_code` varchar(7) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dev_act_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

It would seem that everything is fine, but I get the following error and I don't understand why. The alias is correct, the field exists, yet the system can't find it.

```
WordPress database error: [Unknown column 'a.dev_act_id' in 'field list']
```

By request, here are the other three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `pbq_idp_plan_actions` (
  `dev_plan_act_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dev_act_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dev_plan_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `action_status` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `not_earlier` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deadline` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dev_plan_act_id`),
  KEY `dev_act_id` (`dev_act_id`,`dev_plan_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
    
CREATE TABLE `pbq_idp_credit_bags` (
  `credit_bag_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dev_plan_act_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `competence_id` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `credits` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`credit_bag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

CREATE TABLE `pbq_idp_wallets` (
  `wallet_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dev_act_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `competence_id` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `credits` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`wallet_id`),
  KEY `dev_act_id` (`dev_act_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post the tables as text not image. Run `show create table pbq_idp_plan_actions` and post the output on the question for the 4 tables

Comment: Delimit each part of the table dot column separately. (Or just skip the quotes.)

Comment: @ErgestBasha Done (th etable to show is pbq_idp_dev_actions, anyway.

Comment: @DariodeJudicibus you have only pasted pbq_idp_dev_actions table. I can't test the query with only one table, please post the remaining 3 tables

Comment: @jarlh Do you mean a.'dev_act_id' instead of 'a.dev_act_id'? (where ' is a backtick really)

Comment: Just like that.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Done. I added them at the end of post. Thank you for helping.

Comment: what is the 'field list' ? Are you able to dump that part?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the wrong usage of backticks as can be seen in [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/3YFueyMB) and the column `action_expiration` doesn't exist on `pbq_idp_plan_actions` table.

Backticks are used in MySQL to select Schema Object Names. Do not put the alias name inside backticks.

Not valid

```
`a.dev_act_id`
```

Valid

```
a.`dev_act_id`.
```

In your case backticks are exces

Comment: Thank you. I try immediately your correction and let you know.